# KeyError: 'data' with Python Instagram API client

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api, keyerror

I'm using this client [`python-instagram`](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) with `Python 3.4.3` on `MacOS`.

Here are my steps:

- Registered a new client on `instagram`, received `client_id` and `client_secret`
- Pip install `python-instagram`
- Copy `sample_app.py` to my mac

I followed the instructions on [`Sample app`](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram#sample-app), I successfully authorized my app via instagram and tried this [list of examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB7Tt.png), but none of them worked. After my click the `<h2>` header and counter of API requests changes and I see `Remaining API Calls = 486/500`.

If I try to get `User Recent Media` an exception `KeyError: 'data'` shows in my terminal. If I delete `try - except` construction, leaving block in `try`, when I'll see 'Error: 500 Internal Server Error'.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/.envs/insta/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
return route.call(**args)
File "/Users/user/.envs/insta/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
rv = callback(*a, **ka)
File "sample_app.py", line 79, in on_recent
recent_media, next = api.user_recent_media()
File "/Users/user/.envs/insta/lib/python3.4/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 197, in _call
return method.execute()
File "/Users/user/.envs/insta/lib/python3.4/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 189, in execute
content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
File "/Users/user/.envs/insta/lib/python3.4/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 151, in _do_api_request
obj = self.root_class.object_from_dictionary(entry)
File "/Users/user/.envs/insta/lib/python3.4/site-packages/instagram/models.py", line 99, in object_from_dictionary
for comment in entry['comments']['data']:
KeyError: 'data'
```

All the code I used is from the sample of the official python API client by Instagram.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an open [`Github issue`](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/issues/202) for this bug, a [`fix`](https://github.com/shackra/python-instagram/commit/c7af85fa867bf33a2370bc051c45db07f656e0da) was sent, but it's not merged yet.

Add the one line fix to `models.py` on your installed package.

Open with sudo:

```
sudo vi /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/instagram/models.py  # Use relevant python version
```

On line 99, add this:

```
if "data" in entry["comments"]:
```

Correct indentation on next two lines:

```
       for comment in entry['comments']['data']: 
           new_media.comments.append(Comment.object_from_dictionary(comment))
```

Comment: That worked for me! Some bug... I tested it on Python 3.4.

Comment: It took me a while to discover this bug and "hack" it but I can't fix it on our dockers because they get build from the pip sources. I really hope they merge this fix into the main branch.

Comment: I also have installed python-instagram via pip, but could solve the problem following @Forge instruction. If you type `pip uninstall python-instagram`,  the system will show a list of the files to be uninstalled, with respective locations, including models.py. Say "n" to "Proceed (y/n)?", to NOT uninstall python-instagram, and now you know where the file is.

Comment: What if I want to get comments of the media? With this way, it is possible to get the media info like create time, link, etc. It is only a simple way to pass  the error, but still it does not solve the main problem. You cannot get the comments of the specific media.

Comment: @waterkinq I've been wondering the same thing. Does this mean we can't get comments, or that we'll only get comments when they do exist (avoiding error when they don't)?

Comment: @CaryShindell This solved my problem: 

for comment in entry['comments'].get('data', []):    new_media.comments.append(Comment.object_from_dictionary(comment))

Comment: Ok, doesn't throw an error, but gives empty lists for comments (for posts where I know there are some)

Answer (score 5):

It appears that there is a bug in models.py. If you comment out line 99 and 100 in that file, the "sample app" will work, or at least appears to work. Obviously, this is not a "real" fix but it does show that it is not a problem with the sample Python program, or Instagram.

```
    Line 99  #  for comment in entry['comments']['data']:
    Line 100 #      new_media.comments.append(Comment.object_from_dictionary(comment))
```

Comment: This fix works also for me, but I hope is not the "final" solution

Answer (score 1):

+1 for answer from @forge

For docker users (as asked in a comment), fork the python-instagram repo, edit, and then pip install via github.

Or just use someone else's fork with the following line in your Dockerfile:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/zgazak/python-instagram
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[instagram-api](/questions/tagged/instagram-api) [docker](/questions/tagged/docker)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer just a quick workaround based on the answer by @forge when you are working in environments like docker or an environment that doesn't have a readable terminal.

```
sed -i '99,100 s/^/#/' /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/instagram/models.py
```

Comment: If it's "not really an answer", then you should leave it as a comment when you have enough reputation to leave comments.